# Are these two logical statements involving the unique existential quantifier equivalent?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let $\mathit T(x,y)$ mean "x is a teacher of y." Are the two following logical statements equivalent? 
$$ \exists!x\exists!yT(x,y)  $$
and 
$$ \exists x\exists y\biggl(T(x,y) \land \lnot\Bigl(\exists u\exists v\bigl(T(u,v) \land (u\neq x \lor v \neq y\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)$$
My class today had a big discussion about this and there is still some deabate on whether or not it they are both equivalent.

Comment: What debate was there?

Comment: My professor gave this example, where one of the statements the statement with unique quantifiers is true and the one without is false, so therefore the statements are not equivalent. Here is a list of students, teachers and their relationships. x is a teacher who teaches only y. u is a teacher who teaches students v and f. If you apply this situtation to the statements, you get the result I mentioned above. The class argued that the first statement was false becuase there was more than one teacher in the set. The professor said that didn't matter. Sorry if this is a confusing elaboration.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! If the negation in the second formula only applies to $\exists u$ and should be read as "$\nexists u$ for which ... holds", the second statement does not exclude the possibilty of  $T(u,y)$ for some $u \ne x$. Otherwise, the answer below explains.

Comment: Thank you for the kind welcome. I think I needed an extra set of parentheses there. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Okay, I see what the issue is; I'm going to have to edit my answer, but I don't have the time right now. So I'm going to delete until I can get to it.

Answer (score 3):

Let us examine the situation with the example you gave in a comment:
$$M := \{ x, y, u, v, f \}, \\
T := \{ (x, y), (u, v), (u, f) \}.$$
Now in order to avoid confusion with the members of $M$ let us rename the variables so that the first statement reads $\exists! a \exists! b T(a, b)$.

In order to evaluate the truth value of this statement, let us start with the inner unique existential quantifier, $\exists! b T(a, b)$.  This has a free variable $a$, and we will eventually need its evaluation when $a$ ranges over all values of $M$.  Check that:
$$(\exists!b T(a, b))[a/x] = \exists!b T(x, b) = T,\\
(\exists!b T(a, b))[a/y] = \exists!b T(y, b) = F,\\
(\exists!b T(a, b))[a/u] = \exists!b T(u, b) = F,\\
(\exists!b T(a, b))[a/v] = \exists!b T(v, b) = F,\\
(\exists!b T(a, b))[a/f] = \exists!b T(f, b) = F.$$
From this, you can conclude that $\exists! a \exists! b T(a, b)$ is true.

However, as you observe, $\exists a \exists b (T(a, b) \wedge \lnot(\exists c \exists d (T(c, d) \wedge (a \ne c \vee b \ne d))))$ is false.  To do this in full detail as in the previous part would require over $5^4$ evaluations, yet it should hopefully be clear that since $T$ has more than one element, $\exists c \exists d (T(c, d) \wedge (a \ne c \vee b \ne d))$ is always true no matter what $a$ and $b$ are, and from there you can conclude the overall statement is false.

---

Intuitively, you might think of the first statement as expressing "there is exactly one teacher who has exactly one student", whereas the second statement expresses "there is exactly one teacher-student pair", and convince yourself why the two ideas are expressing different things.

---

Some other counterexamples you might consider: if the domain of discourse is $\mathbb{N}$, then $\exists! x \exists! y, x \ge y$ is true, and so is $\exists! x \exists! y, x > y$.  Yet in both cases, there are clearly numerous distinct pairs of $x, y$ such that $x \ge y$, or distinct pairs of $x, y$ such that $x > y$.

In the original example of $M$ and $T$ above, we have $\exists! a \exists! b T(a, b)$ is true but $\exists! b \exists! a T(a, b)$ is false.  Therefore, $\exists! a$ and $\exists! b$ do not "commute".

---

The second statement above would indeed be a good formalization of the notion that there exists a unique combination of $x$ and $y$ satisfying $T$.  Thus, if that was what you meant in some context, you would want to avoid $\exists! x \exists! y$ because that doesn't mean the same thing.  You might see notations such as $\exists! (x, y), T(x, y)$ for the second.